# What’s the common way to manage URLs when crawling?

Tags: web-crawler

I am trying to program a web-crawler, but now I am wondering: What’s the best method to store all the urls, so that crawlers can work together but do not interfere?

Example:

- Crawler 1 finds a page with 100 URLs
- Crawler 2 finds a page without any URLs
- Crawler 1 and 2 shall **share** the 100 URLs Crawler 1 has found

**My ideas (two different approaches)**

1. Let the `Crawler` scan the page for new URLs

   - save all found URLs in a `Queue` (PriorityQueue) shared by all instances of `Crawler`
   - outsource the URLs to a database as soon as the `Queue` becomes too large (e.g. 80% of the maximum size)
2. Let the `Crawler` save HTML and an `Analyzer` search for URLs later

   - save new URLs to a horizontally scaled database
   - always ask this database for the next URL

**Problems**

1. Is the shared `Queue` a bottle neck?
2. How can I prevent multiple crawlers from getting the same URL twice if database is only eventually consistent?

**Other solutions?**

Are there any other solution? What is the standard solution for web crawlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one question there, but how about this for one general approach.

See this SO [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402485/how-to-compare-two-urls-in-java) regarding determination if two URLs are equivalent.

Then, you really have a lot of options.  My personal favorite would be to write 3 things.

1) A database application that only handles the list of URL's waiting to be visited.
2) A database application that stores important results from visited sites.  Whatever you want to save.
3) An application that can query and post to (1) and then post to (2)

**Why this way?**
You can place (1) and (2) on a single machine.  (3) can run from anywhere, allowing you to run multiple instances from multiple IP addresses.  This will help you navigate service providers and other Network folks, who may be perturbed by your repeated and frequent http requests.

Comment: But can’t 1) become a bottle neck then? If I have a lot of crawlers on different machines and they all want to receive from 1), will 1) always be able to manage it instantly?

Comment: I expect you will spend most of your computing cycles just waiting for responses from the links you find.  The approach I described can scale to whatever bandwidth you have available.  Many ways you can optimize depending on the # of requests you can make in a given period of time and the bandwidth you have to send/rcv results.

Comment: I guess that I should also add that some sites may limit how frequently a single IP address can request links from their servers.  If you distribute the (3)'s onto multiple IP addresses, you can crawls sites faster.

Comment: This open source crawler may help http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/  or checkout this long list at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers

Comment: And this is a more coherent description of the sort of thing I was trying to say: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_web_crawling

Answer (score 3):

[While this is an old question, I'm adding this answer for the sake of searchers landing here]

What you're looking for is a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

While the majority of open source bloom filters you'll find are drop in libraries designed for local access, it's actually fairly trivial to turn them into a web service and therefore a shared resource for multiple nodes.

Here's a very basic example of using [php-bloom-filter](http://code.google.com/p/php-bloom-filter/) with a static cache library:

```
<?php

// assumes $_POST contains a JSON-encoded  array of URLs to check ($links)
// and a unique crawl identifier ($crawl_id)
extract($_POST);

if (!$b = unserialize(Cache::read('filter_'.$crawl_id))) {
    $b = new BloomFilter(100000, 0.001);
}

$return = array();
foreach (json_decode($links, true) as $link) {
    if (!$b->has($crawl_id.'_'.$link)) {
        $return[] = $link;
        $b->add($crawl_id.'_'.$link);
    }
}

// put the filter back into our cache
Cache::write('filter_'.$crawl_id, serialize($b));

echo json_encode($return);
```

Any URLs that make it out of the bloom filter check would then be pushed into your crawl queue for picking up by your crawl nodes.

This kind of implementation is obviously not designed for web-scale crawls, but will be fine for individual site crawls up to 100k pages or more (dependant on your available server resources). Of course, if you really needed your bloom filter to scale horizontally then you could use multiple bloom nodes behind a proxy all using a distributed cache of some description (redis/memcache/ehcache etc). You'll need some clever sharding across cache objects to maintain lookup speed but I'm sure you'll work that out when the need arises.

The only caveat on the above is that you will occasionally get a false negative and end up crawling the same URL more than once - this is a fact of most web crawlers so it's just a case you should handle gracefully in your crawl parsing code.