# Comparing URLs with parameters in Java

Tags: java, url, selenium

These two urls should be the same:

```
http://localhost?asdf=1&qwer=2
http://localhost?qwer=2&asdf=1
```

But using 'equals()' from the URL class, I get that they're different. How can I compare them?

*EDIT: Some background on this question*

I'm creating a Selenium test for some url mapping. I have old url, url it should get mapped to and the actual url. I need to compare the should-be url to the actual url. List of urls is created by client. Urls with the same parameters and values are considered valid if the list of parameters is the same, and they all have the right values (order of those parameters is irrelevant)

Comment: These two URL's are different for me (and for many others :)) and that is why equals method in URL class returns false for that. You should write your own method which compares the query parameter and returns result according to that.

Comment: They are actually the same.  The order of the parameters should have no effect on any J2EE application.

Answer (score 1):

So if I get it right, you want to compare two URL's, regardless of the order of the query part.

There does not seem to be a method for this in the `URL` class, so you'll have to write your own.
Also, `URL` is `final`, you cannot override `URL.equals(Object)`.

Your method could start with calling [`sameFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#sameFile%28java.net.URL%29).
If that evaluates to `true`, you then call [`getQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getQuery%28%29), and split it into it's components - probably with [String.split("\&")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). From there on, you evaluate if the parameters are the same.
Also, don't forget to check if the "#fragment" is equal, if that is important to your application.

Answer (score 0):

URL/URI equals method is broken. At least it doesn't provide results as you would expect.
There are a lot of weird things with it. You might be interested to read

[Mr. Gosling – why did you make URL equals suck?!?](http://brian.pontarelli.com/2006/12/05/mr-gosling-why-did-you-make-url-equals-suck/)

or maybe

[How to compare two URLs in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402485/how-to-compare-two-urls-in-java)

So, don't expect it would be easy.
You can create your custom comparator for your particular case but in general you might have to parse the url string.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to like it, but you could do something like

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost?asdf=1&qwer=2");
URL url2 = new URL("http://localhost?qwer=2&asdf=1");

System.out.println(isEqual(url, url2));

public static boolean isEqual(URL url1, URL url2) {

    boolean isEqual = url1.getAuthority().equals(url2.getAuthority()) &&
                    url1.getPort() == url2.getPort() &&
                    url1.getHost().equals(url2.getHost()) &&
                    url1.getProtocol().equals(url2.getProtocol());

    if (isEqual) {

        String query1 = url1.getQuery();
        String query2 = url2.getQuery();

        if (query1 != null && query2 != null) {

            if (query1.length() == query2.length()) {

                List<String> list1 = getParameters(query1);
                List<String> list2 = getParameters(query2);

                for (int index = 0; index < list1.size(); index++) {

                    String value1 = list1.get(index);
                    String value2 = list2.get(index);
                    if (!value1.equals(value2)) {

                        isEqual = false;
                        break;

                    }

                }

            } else {

                isEqual = false;

            }

        } else {

            isEqual = false;

        }

    }

    return isEqual;

}

protected static List<String> getParameters(String value) {

    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>(25);

    String[] values = value.split("&");
    for (String par : values) {

        if (!par.contains("=")) {
            par += "=null";
        }

        parameters.add(par);

    }

    Collections.sort(parameters);

    return parameters;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with functionality available in the String class.

This approach splits the URLs into two parts, the one before the "?" and the one after (it's fine if no "?" or parameters are present). If the URLs before the "?" are equivalent, the two are "equal" for our purposes.

```
public boolean urlsMatchWithoutQueryParameters(String firstUrl, secondUrl) {
    // Get the portion of the URLs before the "?", and before all parameters.
    String firstUrlWithoutParameters = firstUrl.split("\\?", 2)[0];
    String secondUrlWithoutParameters = secondUrl.split("\\?", 2)[0];

    return firstUrlWithoutParameters.equals(secondUrlWithoutParameters);
}
```

---

The code is a little crowded, so you could do something pull out the String logic into a helper like so:

```
public boolean urlsMatchWithoutQueryParameters(String firstUrl, secondUrl) {
    return getUrlWithoutParameters(firstUrl).equals(getUrlWithoutParameters(secondUrl));
}

public String getUrlWithoutParameters(String url) {
    // Get the portion of the URL before the "?", and before all parameters.
    return url.split("\\?", 2)[0];
}
```

---

*Note:* This ignores URL anchors (e.g., #photos in the url www.example.com/profiles/user123#friends).
To for anchors, simply replace `"\\?"` with `"#"` in `split("\\?", 2)`.

Answer (score -1):

I like this question so I wrote this little demo.  (Sorry, I used the StringUtils class for the substrings)

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class URLDemo
{

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws MalformedURLException
    {
        String url1 = "http://localhost?asdf=1&qwer=2";
        String url2 = "http://localhost?qwer=2&asdf=1";
        URL url11 = new URL(StringUtils.substringBefore(url1, "?"));
        URL url22 = new URL(StringUtils.substringBefore(url2, "?"));

        if (url11.equals(url22))
        {
            // url are equal but still need to check the parameters
            List<String> params1 = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(StringUtils.substringAfter(url1, "?"), "&"));
            List<String> params2 = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(StringUtils.substringAfter(url2, "?"), "&"));

            // need to check both ways
            if (params1.containsAll(params2) && params2.containsAll(params1))
            {
                System.out.println("URLs are the same");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("URLs are different");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll probably have to do something like this. I really find it hard to believe that there isn't a tested library with such a comparison. I'm always worried about how such code would handle encoding, ending slashes ("localhost/" vs. "localhost") and things like that. I generally hate reinventing the wheels....

Answer (score -3):

Well these **two url are infact different**

```
http://localhost?asdf=1&qwer=2
http://localhost?qwer=2&asdf=1
```

//////// EDITED PART //////////

Try this....

**-** Use `openStream()` on **both** the url.

**-** Save both of them as 2 `String` Objects, or `StringBuilder` instead.

**-** Now compare both of them using `equals()`.

**-** This will solve the problem, i think so....

Comment: Note that the parameters are the same, just a different order. I think the question is about that.

Comment: @S.L.Barth `equals()` method checks whether the Objects pointed by the Object Reference Variable are same or different, `as both the url are different, 2 different objects are created on the heap, so we get that both are diff...as simple as that....`

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra equals is overrided... you're not comparing heap addresses there.

Comment: I get that, but the OP's problem is (apparently) how to find if the URL's are the same _modulo_ the order of parameters. He'll probably need to write his own Comparator.