# HTTP/FTP: Does trailing slash in URL mean another resource

Tags: http, url, ftp

I have two URLs:

```
http://example.com/foo
```

and

```
http://example.com/foo/
```

Are they different URLs or the same? The same question is and about FTP protocol `(ftp://example.com/foo[/])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two URLs in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402485/how-to-compare-two-urls-in-java)

Comment: Take a look at the answers; the URLs you suggest are clearly different, but that question has a little more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the URI standard, the relevant section is [*Normalization and Comparison*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6):

1. After doing a [simple string comparison](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.1), these URIs are not equivalent.
2. After applying [syntax-based normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2), these URIs are not equivalent.
3. For [scheme-based normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3), you have to refer to the specifications of the `http`/`https` and `ftp` URI schemes, and check if any scheme-specific rules are defined:

- For [`http`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1)/[`https`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.2), these rules are in the section [*http and https URI Normalization and Comparison*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.3), and there don’t seem to be any for your case.
- For [`ftp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.2), there don’t seem to be defined any normalization/comparison rules.

4. For [protocol-based normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.4), you have to take something like redirects into account (in case of `http`).

**tl;dr:** The URIs are *not* equivalent.

---

Note that this is not the case for an empty path in HTTP(S) URIs, as the section linked above defines:

> […] an empty path component is equivalent to an absolute path of "/" […]

So the following URIs *are* equivalent:

```
http://example.com/

http://example.com
```

---

By the way, for the protocol-based normalization, the standard gives your case as an example:

> […] For example, if they observe that a URI such as
>
> ```
> http://example.com/data
> ```
>
> redirects to a URI differing only in the trailing slash
>
> ```
> http://example.com/data/
> ```
>
> they will likely regard the two as equivalent in the future. […]

Comment: Both you and @Martin Prikryl have correct answers, but this one answers in terms of the documented URI standard.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are different resource.

---

It's particularly important in HTML.

If you have a relative link `bar` (`<a href="bar">blah</a>`):

- In the `https://www.example.com/foo`, that link resolves to the `https://www.example.com/bar`
- While in the `https://www.example.com/foo/`, that link resolves to `https://www.example.com/foo/bar`

But HTTP servers will usually redirect the `https://www.example.com/foo` to the `https://www.example.com/foo/`, when `foo` is a folder, to avoid this confusion.

---

With the FTP protocol, it's probably client-specific, as the FTP protocol itself does not work with URLs.

So it depends on the FTP client how it behaves, if you use the `https://www.example.com/foo`, when the `foo` is actually a folder. The *"FTP client"* in this case typically means a web browser, as these work with URLs. Dedicated FTP clients usually do not work with URLs either.